# While downloading a folder contents from Amazon S3 using boto3, only some files get downloaded and for others, i get the following exception :

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, cloud-storage

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 130, in download_file
extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py", line 307, in download_file
future.result()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 73, in result
return self._coordinator.result()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 233, in result
raise self._exception
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 255, in _main
self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\download.py", line 353, in _submit
**transfer_future.meta.call_args.extra_args
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 324, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 622, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Why am i getting this exception only for some files? i've a S3 folder (/test/files/) with 25 files (A1.tmp, A2.tmp etc .... A25.tmp). only 2 files (A5.tmp, A6.tmp) are getting downloaded. Could anyone please suggest a solution for this? any help is appreciated.

Code i'm using :

def download_contents_s3(self,
                             access_key,
                             secret_access_key,
                             region,
                             content,
                             dir_name) :

```
    session=self.create_session_s3(access_key,secret_access_key,region)

    if path.exists(dir_name) is False :

        os.mkdir(dir_name)



    for item in content :


        os.chdir(dir_name)

        path_to_file = ("/".join(item.strip("/").split('/')[1:]))

        container_name = Path(item).parts[1]

        b = session.Bucket(container_name)

        gen = b.objects.all()

        li=[]

        for i in gen :

            li.append(i.key)

        if path_to_file in li :


            fl = os.path.basename(path_to_file)

            print(fl)
            c = self.splitall(item)

            for i in range(1,len(c)-1) :

                if path.exists(c[i]) is False :
                    os.mkdir(c[i])
                os.chdir(c[i])


            session.meta.client.download_file(container_name,fl,fl)

            for i in range(1,len(c)) :

                os.chdir("..")


        else :

            c = self.splitall(item)

            for i in range(1,len(c)) :

                if path.exists(c[i]) is False :
                    os.mkdir(c[i])
                os.chdir(c[i])

            g = b.objects.filter(Prefix=path_to_file)

            for i in g :

                s = os.path.basename(i.key)

                print(s)

                try :

                    session.meta.client.download_file(container_name,s,s)

                except botocore.exceptions.ClientError :

                    print("exception")


            for i in range(1,len(c)) :

                os.chdir("..")
```

Comment: Are u able to download same set of files using AWS CLI ? 'aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/myDirectory/Files/ . --recursive'

Comment: Hello Venkatesh, yes, i'm able to download those files using AWS CLI.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Hello, added the code to the question. I request you to take a look now.